# How to make MS Outlook remove tags from email I sent?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am looking for a way to configure outlook to remove my tags from emails I sent. It happens sometimes that I tag an email I become, and reply/forward it to somebody else. I do not want to share how I categorize the emails. Is there a way to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy. Just create a rule for all outbound mail that clears message categories.

In *Outlook Rules Wizard*:

1. Apply rule on messages I send, Next
2. Leave all checks clear, Next,
3. Confirm processing all messages.
4. Set check on *Clear message's category*.
5. Finish